# Issue with Audit Feature's Custom Time Filter on Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect, audit

I am attempting to look at changes through the auditing feature that occur between several hours on the same day on Enterprise Architect Version 13.

This is done through the filter settings where I set the appropriate time range but this does not work as it should. Instead it always returns:

[image]

Regardless of any time range I enter within the same day it returns 00:00:00 to 00:00:00 on same day.

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in EA. Most likely you are the first ever to use this (silly enough, the date is preset with 1.1.1900 for custom date). The bug is also present in V12. You need to report that as [bug](http://sparxsystems.com/support/forms/bug_report.html).